# Is there any security benefits from checking `password` == `confirmPassword` on the server?

Tags: security, passwords

In "change password" and "create user" forms, I check the equality of `password` and `confirmPassword` on the client side. 
Is there any security benefits on checking that on the server as well?

Comment: I don't think so. The main purpose of that is to make sure user sets the password that he thinks he is setting.

Comment: It's best to do it server side in case the client has JavaScript disabled. There is no need to do it client-side. Server-side is far simpler because you code your solution once. The only way to properly "secure" the system is to use SSL and salted password hashing in your database. I'd also recommend using a tried and tested password/hashing library to help you simplify your script.

Answer (score 1):

Checking in the client side code would allow you to give the user instant feedback, checking on the server allows you to perform proper validation.

You should never perform any real validation on the client side, instead it should be only for the user's benefit.

Change password forms should always prompt for the users current password to prevent XSS, also dont call your 'old password' field have the same field name as your login or signup password fields to prevent auto-completion by browsers.

It also wouldn't hurt to have single use tokens embedded in hidden fields

Comment: Nice approach. So true.

Comment: The question is not about server/client side validation in general.

Comment: The security concern is that certain fields are not being validated by the server, human error is reduced if you have a policy of doing all fields which have been passed in